# Kendo UI (Scheduler) - Show Event on Left Bottom instead of Top Left

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

How can I place Event box at the bottom of the box instead of Top Left?

```
Demo: http://codepen.io/areddyprasad/pen/mVejxw
```

**Reference Image:**

[image]

Comment: **@middaparka**... tried using CSS absolute position to bottom:0 with no luck :(... As I am not good at coding, any help can be appreciated... sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way it's to add

```
top: auto !important;
```

to your `.k-scheduler-header .k-event` class.

Your example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPaVZq

Comment: Thanks **@Jarosław Kończak**.... but somehow it is not working in below example :(

http://codepen.io/areddyprasad/pen/jWWPJL